# angular Error: [$parse:syntax]

Tags: angularjs

cant understand whats wrong with that code:

```
<div ng-show="advices.length > 3" ng-click="advicesLimit = (advicesLimit == 3)?advices.length:3" class="event more_history" style="padding: 0px;margin: 0px;background-color: white;">
            <center class="ng-binding" style="font-size: 15px;padding-bottom: 4px;border-top: 2px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.92);">
                <span ng-show="advicesLimit == 3">{{'More'|translate}} {{advices.length - 3}}</span>
                <span ng-show="advicesLimit > 3">{{'Fill'|translate}}</span>
                <i ng-show="advicesLimit == 3" class="down icon" style="padding-left: 10px;"></i>
                <i ng-show="advicesLimit > 3" class="up icon" style="padding-left: 10px;"></i>
            </center>
        </div>
```

And i have an error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.2/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=expected%20%3A&p2=null&p3=3%3Fadvices&p4=3%3Fadvices
    at Error (native)
    at http://127.0.0.1/js/built/mainLib.js?b25:39:456
    at Ya.throwError (http://127.0.0.1/js/built/mainLib.js?b25:193:322)
    at Ya.ternary (http://127.0.0.1/js/built/mainLib.js?b25:197:221)
    at Ya.assignment (http://127.0.0.1/js/built/mainLib.js?b25:196:366)
    at Ya.expression (http://127.0.0.1/js/built/mainLib.js?b25:196:319)
    at Ya.filterChain (http://127.0.0.1/js/built/mainLib.js?b25:195:449)
    at Ya.statements (http://127.0.0.1/js/built/mainLib.js?b25:195:273)
    at Ya.parse (http://127.0.0.1/js/built/mainLib.js?b25:192:147)
    at $get (http://127.0.0.1/js/built/mainLib.js?b25:125:360) <div ng-show="advices.length >
```

All variables not undefined. When i get length to console from controller everything is okey, but this one gives me a mistake. And when i delete ng-click no error detected, so problem can be in ng-click.

Comment: Found the problem. I have turned on Angular extension. When i turned it off everything becoms OK.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I have turned on Angular extension. When i turned it off everything becoms OK